# How to expose exemplar in prometheus go_client

Tags: prometheus

prometheus go_client seem to have exemplar support for Histogram and Counter.
But I've been struggling create a hello-world app exposing some random exemplar.

I've seen the example here https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/blob/master/examples/random/main.go#L99

But even if I download the example and run. I still couldn't see exemplar show up.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging, use:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/openmetrics-text' localhost:8080/metrics
```

[image: Use curl -H 'Accept: application/openmetrics-text' localhost:8080/metrics for debugging]

[Details](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/issues/815)